# Sierpinksi Triangle using Chaos Game - Incorrect Plot (missing points)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, chaos

I am trying to generate a Spierpinki Triangle in Python using the Chaos game.
The computations of the points to plot seem correct however, instead of thousands of points plotted, only 10 or so are plotted.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Defining vertices
t = np.linspace(0, (2 * math.pi), 4)
v = np.array([[math.cos(t[0]), math.cos(t[1]), math.cos(t[2])],
              [math.sin(t[0]), math.sin(t[1]), math.sin(t[2])]])

# Defining Starting point
T = np.array([[0.5, 0], [0, 0.5]])
x = np.array([rand.random() - 0.5, rand.random() - 0.5]).reshape(2, 1)

res = np.zeros((2, 1))
n = 10000
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(2):
        k = rand.randint(0, 2)
        res = np.expand_dims(res, axis=0)
        res = np.multiply(T, np.subtract(x[j], v[:, k])) + v[:, k]
        xx = [x for (x, y) in res]
        yy = [y for (x, y) in res]
        plt.plot(xx, yy, 'b.')

plt.show()
```

[image: Sierpinksi Triangle Plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to SO. Your problem is well-explained. Your code is self-contained. What a great first question.

> The computations of the points to plot seem correct.

Not quite. There are multiple issues with your code. Some are actual mistakes, albeit easy to make ones. For example, `rand.randint(0,2)` gives you a random integer on the interval [0, 2). Notice that you can never get a 2 this way, and your third vertex is never selected.

The much bigger problem is the complexity of your code. An inner loop over `j` that doesn't change anything. Matrix multiplication to subtract 2 points from one another. Etc. It gets so complicated, that you never notice that `x`/`res` never gets updated, such that you are plotting the same points over and over again. You should strive to express ideas simpler. Elegant mathematical notation can be a starting point for your code but it is rarely the endpoint.

Here is my version of your code, simplified.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Defining vertices
t = np.linspace(0, (2 * np.pi), 4)
v = np.array([[np.cos(t[0]), np.cos(t[1]), np.cos(t[2])],
              [np.sin(t[0]), np.sin(t[1]), np.sin(t[2])]])

# Defining Starting point
x = np.array([0., 0.])

# Loop
for k in np.random.randint(3, size=1000):
    x += 0.5 * (v[:, k] - x)
    plt.plot(x[0], x[1], 'b.')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Your explanation and implementation are strait to the point, and easy to understand. :)